# Visual Studio 17.6.1 Update: EF6 no longer generating classes

Tags: entity-framework-6, visual-studio-2022

Visual Studio Update, Entity Framework 6, Windows 10.

I updated Visual Studio to Version 17.6.1 and when I recreate my EF model (DB First) none of the classes are generated.

This worked fine right before the update.

I tried reinstalling VS as well as EF, but none of the classes are generated.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

- I had the same issue.
- I made a single change in the **EF6.Utility.CS.tt.include** file.
- Make a copy of this file before editing it, just in case you want to revert.
- Its location is here: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes" folder.
- Code before line 1920 change:

```
    private DynamicTextTransformation(object instance)
    {
        _instance = instance;
        Type type = _instance.GetType();
        _write = type.GetMethod("Write", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        _writeLine = type.GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        _generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        _host = type.GetProperty("Host");
        _errors = type.GetProperty("Errors");
    }
```

- Code after line 1920 change:

```
    _generationEnvironment = type.GetProperty("GenerationEnvironment", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
```

- So only add " | BindingFlags.Public"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).